How to Fix Python Bug in "RandomEffects" Library? (PanelOLS library works with same data)
I generated data with a simulation and used it to run both a random effects and fixed effects model. The data works with the "PanelOLS" libary (for fixed effects), but when I use the "RandomEffects" library I get an error "ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs".
I am confident this is not an issue with the data because if I put the same data into Stata, the random effects model works with no problems.
Below is my Colab code for reference:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16oHu221hzgMRwtSJYidvIGMKYrASSwBL?usp=sharing
The relevant code can be accessed via the headers (Base Case > Set Up & Create Data), and then (Base Case > Run Model - Random Effects)
I looked at documentation for this library and some semi-related stack overflow posts. At the bottom I'll summarize what I've tried, but it's probably easier to look at the comments in my code:

I've:

Ran the same data through the "PanelOLS" library, no errors are thrown
Changed all columns to float datatype, but it is ineffective
Confirmed there were no nans present
Tried the code below, and even confirmed tempX.shape[0]==tempY.shape[0] (which addresses the error Python throws when running the code below)

mod = RandomEffects(tempY, tempX)
mod = RandomEffects(tempX['y'], tempX[['constant','gender','age']])
